# error: value fill is not a member of object Array

Tags: scala, functional-programming, java

```
scala> Array.fill(3){ math.random }
<console>:6: error: value fill is not a member of object Array
       Array.fill(3){ math.random }
```

Am I missing something here? I can't get any of my book's examples or even the examples write out of the scala source code to work.

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.7.7final (OpenJDK Server VM, Java 1.6.0_20)
```

Comment: Wow 2.7.7 ... that feels like decades ago. :-)

Comment: @soc - I thought it went well with my lava lamps and shag carpet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `Array` doesn't have a `fill` method in Scala 2.7.7... that's pretty old. You should probably just upgrade to a more recent version. Here's my output for the exact same code... note the version:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.0.1 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_21).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> Array.fill(3){ math.random }
res0: Array[Double] = Array(0.1074472419841086, 0.06627471316010758, 0.08994384621689899)
```